# Dynamically adding handlers in Netty pipeline by detecting type of Protobuf Objects

Tags: java, netty, protocol-buffers

I have a Netty pipeline in Java in which I have protobuf decoders.The problem is that if I pass a different type of protobuf object through the pipeline, It fails. Is there any way I could first find out what type of protobuf object is coming through the pipeline and then add handlers to the pipeline.
Here is the code that I currently use for handling a single protobuf object:

```
public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();

        // Enable stream compression (you can remove these two if unnecessary)
        if (compress) {
            pipeline.addLast("deflater", ZlibCodecFactory.newZlibEncoder(ZlibWrapper.GZIP));
            pipeline.addLast("inflater", ZlibCodecFactory.newZlibDecoder(ZlibWrapper.GZIP));
        }

        /**
         * length (4 bytes).
         * 
         * Note: max message size is 64 Mb = 67108864 bytes this defines a
         * framer with a max of 64 Mb message, 4 bytes are the length, and strip
         * 4 bytes
         */
        pipeline.addLast("frameDecoder", new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(67108864, 0, 4, 0, 4));

        // decoder must be first
        pipeline.addLast("protobufDecoder", new ProtobufDecoder(WorkMessage.getDefaultInstance()));
        pipeline.addLast("frameEncoder", new LengthFieldPrepender(4));
        pipeline.addLast("protobufEncoder", new ProtobufEncoder());

        // our server processor (new instance for each connection)
        pipeline.addLast("handler", new WorkHandler(state));
    }
```

Comment: I think it's not out-of-box. The raw Protobuf binary format doesn't contain the type information so you need to write it by yourself and parse it.

Comment: @zsxwing can you point me to some resources which might help me in doing that.